# Create new line on TOML file

Tags: toml

I am trying to understand the TOML structure and

```
[[servers]]
ip = "10.0.0.1"
role = "frontend"
[[servers]]
ip = "10.0.0.2"
role = "backend"

developer = "developer_name"
```

If i parse the above the get the json as

```json
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "ip": "10.0.0.1",
      "role": "frontend"
    },
    {
      "developer": "developer_name",
      "ip": "10.0.0.2",
      "role": "backend"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the developer is nested into second object.  But i need developer in the root.

I use this website to verify the TOML [TOML Parser](https://toml-parser.com/)

**expected result**

```json
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "ip": "10.0.0.1",
      "role": "frontend"
    },
    {
      "ip": "10.0.0.2",
      "role": "backend"
    }
  ],
  "developer": "developer_name"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key/value pairs within Toml tables are not guaranteed to be in any specific order.
The way to get 'developer' in the root table is to place it before the 'servers' array of tables:

```
developer = "developer_name"
[[servers]]
ip = "10.0.0.1"
role = "frontend"
[[servers]]
ip = "10.0.0.2"
role = "backend"
```

This will result in this Json structure:

```
{
    "developer": "developer_name",
    "servers": [
    {
        "ip": "10.0.0.1",
        "role": "frontend"
    },
    {
        "ip": "10.0.0.2",
        "role": "backend"
    }]
}
```

This small example could also be formatted with an inline array:

```
servers = [{ip = "10.0.0.1", role = "frontend"}, {ip = "10.0.0.2", role = "backend"}]
developer = "developer_name"
```

That would result in the same Json structure.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Unfortunately I did not want to touch the 3rd party library. So wrote another piece of code in my js file to rearrange and solve.